# Multiple image upload and resize Images : SECURITY

Tags: php, security

Is multiple upload secure in php? How can I prevent security holes?

Comment: If you validate uploaded files before saving it is secure.

Comment: what about exploit with GIF images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/19600803/Secure-file-upload-in-PHP-web-applications) is a good manual to how to protect uploaded files using php including protection from GIF images exploit.

Comment: I have found this link too:
http://www.mysql-apache-php.com/fileupload-security.htm

Answer (score 1):

If your really paranoid you can re-create the image after upload (with imageMagick for example) and save the newly created image on the server.
Then it will definitely be secure.